# Deploying RoR app to Blacknight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Does anyone know how to deploy a RoR app to blacknight i.e. what changes do i need to make to the routes?

Answer (score 0):

Blacknight does not offer Ruby on Rails on shared hosting plans. You would need a cloud server if you want to use Ruby on Rails (see: http://www.blacknight.com/cloud-hosting.html )